# insert a blank space

Tags: regex, space

I am trying to use a search and replace function in B2GO (a piece of bioinformatics software).  The search and replace GUI uses REGULAR EXPRESSIONS.  I would like to change "contig_1" to "contig 1".  In other words, I'd like to replace the underscore with an actual space.  What is the character I would use?  "\s" inserts an "s" - is there another way to specify a space?  [:space:] can't be used, the box won't except ":".

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a regular expression? Isn't this a simple find and replace?

Comment: I haven't used the software you're talking about what have you tried the space bar? Is copying and pasting onto another program to do the search and replace an option?

Comment: NO.  I don't have a choice about the regex - that the way the programme is - please don't ask me why - it's unhelpful.  No,  the space bar won't work

Comment: space bar won't work

Answer (score 0):

Use a literal space by pressing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to replace your match with .